# Exec To Powershell returns different from running directly to Powershell

Tags: php, powershell, exec

I have the following code implemented:

```
$ServiceName = $_GET['Service'];
exec("echo . | powershell.exe -c get-service ".$ServiceName,$OutputArray);
        echo "<pre>";
            print_r($OutputArray);
        echo "</pre>";
```

My `$ServiceName` is assigned through get, but for this example.

```
$_GET['Service'] = "WinRM"; // Service Name is assigned to WinRM For *Windows Remote Management*
```

Now.. When I run this script, I get the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Get-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'WinRM'.
    [1] => At line:1 char:12
    [2] => + get-service <<<<  WinRM
    [3] =>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (WinRM:String) [Get-Service], Se
    [4] =>    rviceCommandException
    [5] =>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.
    [6] =>    Commands.GetServiceCommand
    [7] => 
)
```

Now, when I open Powershell, and run the following:

`get-service WinRM` I get returned with the following output:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> get-service WinRM

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  WinRM              Windows Remote Management (WS-Manag...
```

This happens on a few other service names such as:

```
$Array = array(
        "DNSServer" => "DNS",
        "DHCP Client" => "DHCP",
        "Web Server" => "IISADMIN",
        "Windows Remote Management" => "WinRM"
    );
```

This fails on `DNS, IISADMIN, WinRM` in this example... But again, from PS I get returned with:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> get-service DNS,IISADMIN,WinRM

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  DNS                DNS Server
Running  IISADMIN           IIS Admin Service
Running  WinRM              Windows Remote Management (WS-Manag...
```

My overall question is how to improve the reporting from Powershell to PHP and get accurate results from both ends?

---

This Does succeed some of the time depending on the service name. For example:

`$ServiceName = "DHCP";` -- Which is why this Name is not included in the error debugging.. I get returned with:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Status   Name               DisplayName
    [2] => ------   ----               -----------
    [3] => Running  DHCP               DHCP Client
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
)
```

Which is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Powershell, consider querying the machine via [COM](http://php.net/com) and [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
$wmi = new COM('WinMgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!root/cimv2');
$result = $wmi->ExecQuery('Select * from Win32_Service where Name="Dhcp"');
foreach ($result as $share) {
    printf(
        'Service: %s - Status: %s %s',
        $share->Name,
        $share->Status,
        PHP_EOL
    );
}
```

This will print

```
Service: Dhcp - Status: OK
```

The available properties for Win32_Service are listed here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa394418(v=vs.85).aspx

An alternative would be to `exec` wmic:

```
exec('wmic Service where name="DHCP" get name, status /format:csv', $services);
```

Content of `$services` would then be

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Node,Name,Status
    [2] => MYCOMPUTER,Dhcp,OK
)
```

You can parse this easily with `fgetcsv`. An alternate and easy to parse format would be `rawxml` instead of `csv`. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757287(v=ws.10).aspx for details

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I will check over this in a minute, seeing if it works

Comment: After running the first chunk, it returns blank, so does the second.. If i run the `win32_service` library within PHP, i get error 5 which is a permission problem which I do not have to resolve

Comment: Sorry, don't know why this ain't working for you. Both approaches work fine on my win7 machine.

Comment: Perhaps it's a permission fault, because im on a 2008r2 operating system? And I have found a temporary work around, I've got a scheduled task running a PowerShell with the correct privileges, then PHP reading a text file making an array with the necessary information

Comment: this is my temporary solution, as I was stuck; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328299/explode-at-a-varied-whitespace

Comment: @DarylGill as per my comment on that answer, you might be interested in http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_export_csv.htm